# The accuracy of my algorithm is perfect with small numbers and drop when numbers are larger, but not always

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computational-geometry

There is a game in which i have to program the AI and compete with other programers. I am playing that game. It consists in a race, your pod have to pass through some checkpoints in order.

You have some input arguments to use in your algorithm:

```
nextCheckpoint (x,y) -> nX,nY
lastCheckpoint (x,y) -> lnX,lnY
currentposition (x,y) -> x,y
```

and the output of the code is the directión and the thrust.

```
int pod::errorX(){
    int R[2];
    int X1;
    float b;
    int DeltaX;
    //Vector of the line between Checkpoints
    R[0] = nX-lnX;
    R[1] = nY-lnY;
    //calculation of the distance in the X axis between the ship and the line
    b =(R[0]*(lnX-x) + R[1]*(lnY-y))/((-pow(R[0],2))-(pow(R[1],2)));
    X1 = lnY + b*R[0];
    DeltaX = x-X1;
    cerr<<"Dx: "<<DeltaX<<endl;
    return DeltaX;

}
```

I also have the equivalent pod::errorY()

finally:

```
DirectionX = nX-errorX();
DirectionY = nY-errorY();
```

Here some pictures of what I am doing:

[the theory of what should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiqOh.jpg)

I want to do this becouse most of the times the inertia make my ship orbitate the checkpoints, this consume a lot of time and makes me loose the race.

Well now let's face the problem, it works sometimes and others is not even close.

When the inputs are small.
like

```
nX= 2;
nY= 2;
lnX=0;
lnY=0;
x=0;
y=0;
```

The output is:

```
directionX = 3
directionY = 1
```

But when they are bigger:

```
nX= 6553;
nY= 7817;
lnX=13044;
lnY=1908;
x=13921;
y=3530;
```

the output:

```
DirectionX=6940;
DirectionY=1907;
```

I do not know what happen. Maybe becouse b is decimal? is there any error that i havent seen?

Maybe this code is more confortable to test becouse you dont need the game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int lnX = 13044;
    int lnY = 7817;
    int nX = 13044;
    int nY = 1908;

    int x = 13921;
    int y = 3530;

    int R[2]={};

    //Vector de la recta entre Checkpoints
    R[0] = nX-lnX;
    R[1] = nY-lnY;
    //puro algebra, para calcular el desfase de X
    int X1,DeltaX;
    long double b;
    b =(R[0]*(lnX-x) + R[1]*(lnY-y))/((-pow(R[0],2))-(pow(R[1],2)));
    X1 = lnY + b*R[0];
    DeltaX = x-X1;
    //desfase de y;
    int Y1,DeltaY;
    Y1 = lnY+b*R[1];
    DeltaY = y-Y1;

    //dirección
    int DirectionX;
    int DirectionY;

    DirectionX = nX-DeltaX;
    DirectionY = nY-DeltaY;
    cout<<X1<<" "<<Y1<<endl;
    cout<<DeltaX<<" "<<DeltaY<<endl;
    cout<<b<<" "<<DirectionX<< " "<<DirectionY<<endl;
```

Comment: you are welcome, but to be honest, after reading half i skipped the rest to see a question at the end. unfortunately I didnt find any ;). It is not quite clear what is your question

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Looks like you could be doing integer math when you should be doing floating math, and then truncating or rounding if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this line right?:
`X1 = lnY + b*R[0];`
Or should it be `X1 = lnX + b*R[0];`